# inserting data into database using jquery ajax submit button codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am trying to insert data into the database using the codeigniter framework, i tried many solutions i couldn't find a problem ., can somebody suggest me the proper answer after adding $this->model->('contact_model'); my page is blank

my controller pages.php

```
  <?php

  class pages extends CI_Controller{
  function index{
  $this->load->model('contact_model');      
  $this->load->view('pages/index');
          }
}
 ?>

enter code here
```

my view index.php

```
<form id="submit" action="<?php echo site_url();?>/models/contact_model">

  <input type="text" id="name" >    
  <input type="email" id="email" >
  <textarea placeholder="Message"  id="message"></textarea>
  <button type="button" id="submit1">Send</button>
  <a id="ack"></a>          
</form>
```

my model contact_model.php

```
<?php
 class contact_model extends CI_Model{    

    function insert_entry()

    {
        $data = array(
        'name' => 'name' ,
        'email' => 'email' ,
        'message' => 'message');

            $this->db->insert('contactus', $data); 
    }
                                }
```

?>

custom.js file

```
$("#submit1").click(function){
$.post($("#submit").attr("action"),
       $("#submit :input").serializeArray(),


       function(data)
       {

       $("div#ack").html(data); 
       }); 

$("#submit1").submit(function(){
return false;
   // window.location.href="/application/models/";
 });


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :3 
this is ajax to post data in page to models ...

```
$.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo base_url();?>/pages/",
    type : 'POST',
    data :{
           "name":$("#nametags").val(),
           //more in here
    },
    success : function(data) {
});
```

in controler

```
 class pages extent CI_Controller{
function index() {}
function insert_data(){
       //call function insert data
 $data = array(
    'name' => 'name' ,
    'email' => 'email' ,
    'message' => 'message');

        $this->db->insert('contactus', $data); 
    }
    }
```

your url is: /insert_data

Comment: still i have a problem, at the url : localhost/ci/ when i give i get 404 error not found message

Comment: post here your address of model in your website

Comment: controller is ci/application/controller/pages

Comment: index file is in view/pages/index.php  , database file is in models/contact_model.php

Comment: http://localhost/ci/index.php/pages/ pages is blank  
 my controller

     <?php

    class pages extends CI_Controller{

     function index{

    
    $this->load->model('contact_model');      
    $this->load->view('pages/index');


 }

     }

    ?>

Comment: commit: you should how to know your page you will post. and replace it in my code.

Comment: example: your models is : cd/application/controller/contact_model. 
replace **url:..** to  **url: cd/application/controller/contact_model**

Comment: <?php

class pages extends CI_Controller{

function view($page='index'){

    
//$this->load->model('contact_model');      
$this->load->view('pages/index');


 }

}

?>

Comment: now after doing the above changes i got my front end

Comment: i have a doubt you have defined everything in my controller/pages and a javascript file . what about my models/contact_model ??

Comment: I mean insert 1 function. **function insert_data** into **pages** controller because your index.php is of **pages controller** if your post to **insert_data**, it will be call function **insert_data** on controller **pages**

Answer (score 0):

in action url first parameter won't be model it would be controller name

like follwoing     `<?php echo site_url();?>/controller_name/method_name`

in your case use   `<?php echo site_url();?>/pages/`

```
$.ajax({
url : "<?php echo site_url();?>/pages/insert_data",
type : 'POST',
data :{"name":$("#name").val(),"email":$("#email").val(),"message":$("#message").val()},
success : function(data) {

$("div#ack").html(data);
```

});

and create a function **in controller**

```
function insert_data()
{
  $this->load->model('contact_model');
  $this->contact_model->insert_entry();
}
```

Comment: i changed it nothing happened, my controller is in ci/application/controller/pages

Comment: <?php echo base_url();?>/pages/ no need need add this is html file action tag ??

Comment: i set everything nothing happened, can you please look into my code again

Comment: Check edited code. you can't call model directly. You have to create a method in controller then model function will use in that controller.

Comment: insert_entry function  where should i write in contact_model ??